# What's the proper way to upgrade a single grails project lib jar file?

Tags: grails

Specifically, I want to upgrade to a newer version of the httpcore jar (I have httpcore-4.0.1.jar and need a newer version that contains the org.apache.http.entity.mime package) without upgrading the entire grails project.

From what I've found so far, best practice seems to point to doing something in BuildConfig.groovy under the dependencies section, but I haven't found any documentation yet that explains how I should be formatting the dependency declaration (or even confirming that this would be the right place to do it). It seems to be the closest thing to a Rails project's Gemfile, which I'm more familiar with, which is why it's the place I'm currently looking to handle this. If there's another, better place to be defining that, please let me know.

I've found some suggestions that .jar files can simply be copied into the lib folder and will be picked up, but I worry that .jar files for default libraries may be overwritten and/or not be registered correctly if I do it this way.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused by your question.  Are you asking how to pull in a specific version of a specific jar to your Grails project?  OR are you asking how to pull in a specific version of a specific jar as a dependency for another jar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, httpcore is a dependency of Grails itself and you want to upgrade the version, without changing the version of Grails itself? You can do this by adding the following to `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // exclude the version of httpcore provided by Grails
        excludes 'httpcore'
    }

    dependencies { 
        // Use version 4.1.3 of the library instead
        compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.3'
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out that it wasn't httpcore that I needed to upgrade, but rather httpmime that I needed to add, but this definitely led me in the right direction, so thank you.

Comment: One thing I was having trouble understanding was how the 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.1.3' line mapped to anything. I could get the 'httpcore' and the '4.1.3' as mapping to the jar file name and version, but there was no actual package with 'org.apache.httpcomponents'. Turns out that that maps to the groupId at search.maven.org and if I uncommented mavenLocal() and mavenCentral() in the BuildConfig.groovy file, it would automatically add these to my project.

Comment: Note also that I was wrong in thinking those .jar files had been automatically added to the /lib directory. They had been manually added. Specifying the libraries this way doesn't seem to require any copy to be in the /lib directory.

Comment: @David if you specify dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy` they will be downloaded from a Maven/Ivy repository and added to the project. If you copy the JARs into lib you're also adding them to the project but bypassing the whole dependency resolution mechanism