# Grails not picking patched jar file

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-2.0, datastore

I am working on grails 2.0.3 project. On the way I noticed that following dependency of grails 2.0.3: **org.grails:grails-datastore-core:1.1.4.RELEASE** had a bug. So I patched the jar file and placed it in **lib** folder of grails. In **BuildConfig.groovy** excluded grails jar file and gave my own dependency as given below

```
inherits("global") {
    excludes "grails-datastore-core"
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails:grails-datastore-core:1.1.4.RELEASE'
}
```

Then ran following steps:

- grails clean
- grails compile --refresh-dependencies
- grails run-app

but got following error:

```
2013-06-05 16:39:14,613 20831 ERROR     [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager] (pool-7-thread-1:) Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [domainClass:2.0.3]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/core/SoftThreadLocalMap
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/core/SoftThreadLocalMap
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/grails/datastore/mapping/core/SoftThreadLocalMap
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore.<clinit>(AbstractDatastore.java:46)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.SoftThreadLocalMap
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 7 more
2013-06-05 16:39:14,714 20932 ERROR [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager] (pool-7-thread-1:) Error configuring dynamic methods for plugin [hibernate:2.0.3]: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.AbstractDatastore
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:171)
... 5 more
```

I have tried **renaming the jar** file and changing scope of dependency to **runtime** but no luck.

I have also tried upgrading using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250876/whats-the-proper-way-to-upgrade-a-single-grails-project-lib-jar-file) link but still get the same error.

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Have you checked if the bug is reported or fixed on later versions?

Comment: If you fixed with the same name there's no need to exclude and manually add the dependency.

Comment: @SérgioMichels You mean I just have to put the patched jar in the lib and do not have to exclude and add it. Then how Grails will know that the dependency in the lib folder should be used? Thanks for you help.

Comment: @Alidad The bug is fixed in version 2.x.x.x but its not a RELEASE version that means its not stable one. So i do not want to use it. But on a side note. I also tried the link given in my question to use a later version jar instead of 1.1.4.RELEASE but it did not work for me and gave me same error.

Comment: @khobab this jar is in the lib of Grails install or in your project lb folder? If you replace in the lib of Grails I'm pretty sure that it will be used.

Comment: @SérgioMichels Currently I have put it in my project's lib folder. I will try putting it in grails lib folder and will let you know about my findings. Thanks for advice.