# Exclude httpcore library from Grails 2.4.4 installation and use Maven's

Tags: maven, grails, build, dependencies

I have an application built on Grails 2.4.4 and I see that the default set of dependencies that come with the installation has Apache **`httpcore`** library version 4.2.5

But, I'm writing new code that wants to use APIs from **`httpcore`** version 4.4.6.
So for that I have added the following dependency entry to BuildConfig.groovy:

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.6'
```

But the APIs still refer to the version 4.2.5 from Grails installation but not using the one from .m2 Maven repository which has the version 4.4.6.

Per this SO post [What's the proper way to upgrade a single grails project lib jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7250876/whats-the-proper-way-to-upgrade-a-single-grails-project-lib-jar-file), I have tried doing this in BuildConfig.groovy but no luck:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        excludes 'httpcore'
    }
}
```

Any help in resolving this is really appreciated.

When I run **`grails dependency-report`** I see the **`httpcore`** version **4.4.6**. So it means it's referring to the correct version but then why is it that when I import a class from that dependency it is from **4.2.5** version. Isn't it weird?

Comment: I see that your `dependency-report` indicates that your re using 4.4.6 but you said `"But the APIs still refer to the version 4.2.5 from Grails installation"`.  What evidence do you have that the api is referring to 4.2.5?

Comment: The way I know it is - when I go to the declaration of the class I am importing it's taking me to the older version. However, when I bundle it as WAR and run, it works fine because it's referring to the class from latest version.

Comment: That suggests that the classpath in the IDE is wrong and that the classpath configured in BuildConfig.groovy is correct.  There are a number of reasons those 2 might be out of sync.